# Difference between Kodi and Kodi-standalone? Both launch fine w/o a window manager

Tags: 16.04, server, xorg, kodi

On Ubuntu server 16.04, with only X installed and no window manager, I can still launch Kodi without the `--standalone` switch. For example from a local console:

`xinit kodi -- vtx`

This leads me to ask: what is the difference between "kodi" and "kodi --standalone" if I can still launch kodi without calling the "kodi-standalone" or "--standalone" switch?

I understand `kodi` is for launching with a window manager, and `kodi-standalone` is a script that launches kodi with the --standalone switch.

My question is why, *since I have with no WM installed*, do both `kodi` and `kodi-standalone` (or `kodi --standalone`) launch just fine?

Comment: https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=237093

Comment: Lol i necro'd that thread, 3rd post. Also, wsnipex describes normal as running on top of a window manager, and standalone as running on top of plain X. I have no WM installed, and can launch it both ways, so perhaps my question wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to user FernetMenta over at the Kodi forums:

> The option `standalone` has nothing to do with a window manager (docs/wiki is wrong). With standalone Kodi is i.e. allowed to power the system down and users can change refresh rate in settings dialog.
>
> Running Kodi without a window manager may work but is not a supported and tested scenario.

Comment: The doc is wrong, and "kodi" without standalone has the power off buttons, maybe your'e wrong. and not the doc.

Comment: @pim at least he seems to be right about the refresh rate settings.